# Regular expression quantifier

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression pattern as follows:

```
.*\b(?P<core>[A-Z][0-9]?\b.*)(?P<extra>\b[0-9]+[xX][0-9]+.*)?\.png
```

To match some strings as follows:-

```
UI SCREEN 5-1 F2 ROUND TAB REFLECTION 224x18px.png
```

In Python, I get the following result

```
{u'core': u'F2 ROUND TAB REFLECTION 224x18px', u'extra': None}
```

instead of

```
{u'core': u'F2 ROUND TAB REFLECTION ', u'extra': u'224x18px'}
```

As far as I kown, regex quantifier is greedy by default in python. So I think it should work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please properly format code in the future using ctrl+k or the `{ }` button above the editing box. Click the `?` button for more info on how to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(?P[A-Z][0-9]?\b.*)` probably doesn't do what you think it does ... it will match:

- a character
- then a number, or not
- then a word boundary
- then *absolutely everything after that*

Which swallows everything up to your terminating `.png`  (which should be a `\.png`)

Comment: I have changed .png to \.png.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `?` after your first greedy `.*`

```
import re
x = "UI SCREEN 5-1 F2 ROUND TAB REFLECTION 224x18px.png"
re.search(r'.*\b(?P<core>[A-Z][0-9]?\b.*?)(?P<extra>\b[0-9]+[xX][0-9]+.*)?.png', x).groups()

# OUTPUT
('F2 ROUND TAB REFLECTION ', '224x18px')
```

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot. But why? the '?' of extra group should be greedy as well. It should be tried first then backtrack.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the first greedy expression would consume the rest of it, so the `.*?` would prevent it.

Comment: My understanding is the first greedy expr consumes as much as possible. Then the 2nd greedy expr comes. It will consume as much as possible as well. To achieve the maxism match, the 2nd will backtrack. Is it right? or is there any way to achieve this kind of effect.

Comment: From the python docs http://docs.python.org/library/re.html it states that it will consume as much as possibly in greedy form. Having a second greedy expression doesn't modify that functionality. It does not saying anything about trying the expressions backwards. By the time it gets to the second pattern, the string has been consumed.

Comment: we know .*\.png matches any .png file name. Because although .* consumes everything, it backtracks to make a match to match \.png. Here my question is:-
From what you said, the former greedy expr has privilege over the latter. Is there any way to make the latter greedy expr has the privilege over the former one.

Comment: With all my googling powers combined, I have not found any reference to multiple greedy patterns allowing subsequent patterns to backtrack. Most recent reference I looked at: http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/regular-expressions.html .

Answer (score 0):

Could you write regular expression just like you are using? Because I can't see group name in your regex.

```
>>> re.match(r'(?P<core>[A-Z0-9- ]+) (?P<extra>[0-9]+[xX][0-9]+px)\.png', a).groups()
('UI SCREEN 5-1 F2 ROUND TAB REFLECTION', '224x18px')
```